# TypeError: object DataFrame can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, pandas, asynchronous, async-await, fastapi

I am using fastapi to process some data. Some of the data comes from another API endpoint in the form of the a pandas dataframe.

I have this command:

```
df = await my_lib.get(processedTickers)
```

but in my logs I see this error:

```
TypeError: object DataFrame can't be used in 'await' expression
```

strangely when I test the API I'm calling in a notebook or my local desktop, I get the results but when I call it via a fastapi endpoint, the dataframe is empty.

I'm not sure what is going on wrong so I added await but it's still not working.

Any suggestions on what I can do to debug?

Update1: I've been trying to debug this and am getting the same issue when calling a function within my internal code:

```
async def my_lib():
    return jsonable_encoder("test")
```

but what's odd is this does not work:

```
var = await my_lib()
... #do stuff here
print(my_lib)
return
```

but if I do:

```
var = await my_lib()
print(my_lib)
return
```

then it works but the stuff I want to do is not being done.

Comment: can you provide more code with your example? e.g. your endpoint function that the sample you provided sits in. That will allow us to reproduce the problem in the same way you are experiencing it.

Comment: @Josh Thank you for the comment. It's a bit challenging because it's a private library and a authenticated endpoint. I tried to provide the information as simply as possible, do you have any suggestions of what additional information is required and I'll do my best to get it?

Comment: That's understandable. Are you able to create a sample that produces the same error, excluding anything you can't share? If you could provide a full endpoint example that is giving that issue, I would be able to copy/paste it into a FastAPI app i'm running locally and test that endpoint to try replicate the issue. I'd like to see how you defined the function, endpoint definition etc. as it's quite possible that something else outside of the statement you provided is the cause of the problem, but I will need more info to check it out!

Comment: @Josh Thank you. I updated the question, I noticed if call a function and then do a return statement it works but if I do something right away I call the library then the variable is empty. Within the function is basically a SQL query to get data.

Comment: @Josh further test, if I add a few print statements inbetween the call for the data and the processing of the results, it works. I think it's not really waiting for the results and just proceeding forward. I have await when I call the function so I'm not sure?